# HLS+Fairplay stream resource freeing issue

Tags: reactjs, macos, safari, html5-video, fairplay

**The Context**

I'm using the HTML video element to play HLS+Fairplay streams (VOD and live) in Safari.
My application is a Netflix-like. You can watch a video, stop, and watch another one.
Concretly, the `<video>` tag is created upon each play and destroyed when the player exits.

**The Problem**

Sometimes, after exiting the player, launching a new video causes a `MEDIA_ERR_DECODE` error without anymore explation.
I can trace in my code that the Fairplay certificate and the `CKC` have been correctly retrieved and that the media session has been created and updated (with the `CKC`).
In fact, when I log everything, I see the exact same logs as when it works. Except the final `MEDIA_ERR_DECODE` error.

When I get this error, if I immediately retry to play, the same error happens, but if I wait about 5~10 seconds, it successfully plays. It's like some resource is waiting to be garbage-collected.

**What I tried**

I tried playing non-DRMed videos and it works perfectly: I could play, stop, play, etc. without any issue.

So my guess is something is happening at the EME level.

I've browse the whole Internet (twice) and couldn't come up with a clear explanation.
Most of the hints I found couldn't explain my issue (e.g. bad DRM-encryption, but how could it work the first time?) or solve it (e.g. `videoElement.src = ""`).

I'm throwing a bottle into the sea, here...